# How to render an action and set the URL in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, controllers

How to `render :new` and set the location to `question/:id/new/answer`?

`render :location => new_question_path` sets the location to `question/:id/answer`

`render :location => "/question/#{params[:id]}/new/answer"` did not work either.

Relevant route: `get    '/question/:id/new/answer' => 'answers#new', as: :new_answer`

Comment: Shouldn't be `render :location => "/question/#{params[:id]}/answer/new"`instead?

Answer (score 2):

may be use

```
resources :questions do
  get 'new/answer', :on => :member
end
```

and will see the path via `rake routes`